# How to best loop over each row in certain columns to create a Google Calendar Event, from a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I basically have the below code:

// To identify the Active Spreadsheet and link to Google Calendar

```
function scheduleNotifications(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xyz@gmail.com");
```

// To identify the rows and columns to collect the data from

```
var notifications = spreadsheet.getRange("B2:D1000").getValues();

for (x=0; x<notifications.length; x++) {

    var shift = notifications[x];

    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[];
    var tag = shift[2];
```

// To create the event:

```
eventCal.createEvent(tag, startTime, endTime);
}
```

But the above doesn't work as there is no data in any of the rows from 9 onwards
However I want to get the script to collect data from these rows if they do become populated once I share with my team

Any suggestions?

Comment: [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Answer (score 0):

**Issues:**

- `spreadsheet` is not defined.
- you can use [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) to get the data until the last row with data.

**Modifications:**

from:

```
var notifications = spreadsheet.getRange("B2:D1000").getValues();
```

to:

```
var notifications = sheet.getRange("B2:D"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

**Bonus info:**

Also it makes sense to define `sheet` by its name instead of getting the active sheet. Because if by mistake you have selected a different sheet, then the active sheet will not return the correct sheet.

Change that:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

to something like that (change the name of the sheet accordingly):

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheet_name");`

Answer (score 0):

I would write it way differently:

```js
function addEvents() {
  const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('primary')

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Example sheet')
  const values = sheet.getRange("B2:D").getValues()

  for (let [startTime, endTime, tag] of values) {
    if (startTime != null && endTime != null && tag != null) {
      calendar.createEvent(tag, startTime, endTime)
    }
  }
}
```

The main differences are:

- Getting your own calendar using the keyword `primary`
- Getting the sheet by name (so if you are in another sheet you still read the correct data).
- Getting the open range `B2:D` so if there are only 20 rows, you only get those.
- Use for...of.
- Use destructing assignment.
- Check for empty rows.

The same can also be written in a more functional way:

```js
function addEvents() {
  const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('primary')

  const _events = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Example sheet')
    .getRange("B2:D")
    .getValues()
    .filter(([startTime, endTime]) => startTime != null && endTime != null && tag != null)
    .map(([startTime, endTime, tag]) => calendar.createEvent(tag, startTime, endTime))
}
```

### References

- [CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarById(String))
- [Calendars: get (Calendar API reference)](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get)
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String))
- [for...of (MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Destructuring assignment (MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)